# have the same margin top and right between list items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some list items inside a modal and I want that each list item have the same space or magin between. So Im using margin-bottom: 1rem and margin-right: 1rem, but its not working. For example in larger devices I want to have 3 columns but it appears only two columns with a very large margin in between. Also in medium devices I want 2 columns but with the same margin right and bottom between list items but its not working, the columns have a very large margin in between.

Html:

```
<a  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" href="">Open <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal Title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <ul class="categories-list">
              <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/categories/tags.svg"/>
                <a class="">All Options</a>
              </li>
              <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/categories/video.svg"/>
                <a class="">Option1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/categories/clubbing.svg"/>
                <a class="">Option2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/categories/concert.svg"/>
                <a class="">Option3</a>
              </li>
              <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/categories/conference.svg"/>
                <a class="">Option4</a>
              </li>
              <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/categories/exposition.svg"/>
                <a class="">Option5</a>
              </li>
              <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/categories/certificate.svg"/>
                <a class="">Option6</a>
              </li>
              <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/categories/literature.svg"/>
                <a class="">Option7</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.categories-list{
  display: flex;

  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
.categories-list li{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.categories-list    img{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `categories-list` class, which has the margins you want, is being applied to the `<ul>` element instead of each `<li>` element. This is only going to have an effect on the entire list.